# Insert new data for each text line in python

Tags: python, file, file-writing

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
1,004,59
1,004,65
1,004,69
1,005,55
1,005,57
1,006,53
1,006,59
1,007,65
1,007,69
1,007,55
1,007,57
1,008,53
```

Want to create new text file that will be inserted by 'input', something like this

```
1,004,59,input
1,004,65,input
1,004,69,input
1,005,55,input
1,005,57,input
1,006,53,input
1,006,59,input
1,007,65,input
1,007,69,input
1,007,55,input
1,007,57,input
1,008,53,input
```

I have attempted something like this:

```
with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            line[i] = line[i].strip() + 'input'
    for line in lines:
        f.writelines(line)
```

Not able to get the right approach though.

Comment: cool! what have you attempted before asking?

Comment: I have attempted to do writelines and write commands but couldn't get the desired results.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I did but couldn't get the right approach towards making it right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free code writing service

Comment: @ShubhamKuse Please go through how to write data into a file first. [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: okay shall i post my attempted code?

Comment: Of course! Isn't this yet clear enough?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to be able to read and write to the file in place (at the same time). Python comes with the `fileinput` module which is good for this purpose:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('data.txt', inplace=True):
    line = line.rstrip()
    print line + ",input"
```

## Discusssion

The `fileinput.input()` function returns a generator that reads your file line by line. Each line ends up with a new line (either \n or \r\n, depends on the operating system).

The code then strip off each line of this new line, add the ",input" part, then print out. Note that because of `fileinput` magic, the print statement's output will go back into the file instead of the console.

Answer (score 1):

There are a newline '\n' in every line in your file, so you should handle it.
edit: oh I forgot about the rstrip() function!

```
tmp = []
with open("input.txt", 'r') as file:
    appendtext = ",input\n"
    for line in file:
        tmp.append(line.rstrip() + appendtext)

with open("input.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(tmp)
```

## Added:

Answer by Hai_Vu is great if you use **fileinput** since you don't have to open the file twice as I did.

Answer (score 0):

To do only the thing you're asking I would go for something like

```
newLines = list()
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        newLines.append(line.strip() + ',input\n')

with open('data2.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.writelines(newLines)
```

But there are definitely more elegant solutions